# Avoid jump to Program.cs in Visual Studio 2017 when Debug.BreakAll called on ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

When I want to edit C# code during debug and hit the *break all* button, VS automatically jumps to `Program.cs`. The following screencast shows the problem: I want to edit `HomeController`, VS jumps to `Program.cs`. Now I've to go back to `HomeController`, edit, save and continue so that my changes take effect:

[image: Example]

It's annoying since more clicks are required and I do this often during development cause starting an ASP.NET Core app with debugger take a few seconds. When I do this on every change, Developmemt got slabby. So I'd like to use the `BreakAll` functionality to apply changes directly without restart.

**How can I stop VS from automatically open `Program.cs`? Are there even better ways to edit code during a debug session fast?**

I'm using Kestrel. IIS would be possible if required but I prefer Kestrel since the ASP.NET Core app will run on Linux.

Only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308988/how-to-stop-visual-studio-from-going-to-program-cs-on-break-all-the-pause-butt) question but that's not really usefull: `[DebuggerStepThrough]` stop VS from opening the `Program.cs` tab, but instead open another tab that say there is no code to display, so we've to close this one, too.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint at the point of interest?  Otherwise what you're describing sounds like normal debugger behavior, hitting break all, and the debugger will show you the call stack, but where your code is, as opposed to framework code.

Comment: I also tried setting a breakpoint, same behavior. Could only change this by decorating `Program` class with `[DebuggerStepThrough]` attribute. But this doesn't save the wasted click since now a new tab "halt mode" opens which show no code to display. So it's the same since I need to close this tap instead of `Program.cs`. Isn't there a smarter solution? Can't imagine that I'm the only ASP.NET (Core) developer that find this behavior a waste of time.

Comment: I consider it a massive waste of time, but I found a workflow that works for me. My mouse has a previous page button that I can click to go to the code I was editing, then I simply press F5 to continue the debugging session.